# VB.net - Print datagridView landscape mode

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, landscape, printdocument

I tried almost all tutorials on a lot of websites but all of those I seen doesn't satisfy my needs.

So my requirements is:

The page automatically change to portrait or landscape mode when the data is either few or many.
Like if it has many columns the page settings for printing would change to landscape.
But if it is possible to auto resize the fonts and make it smaller so that all the columns and data, it would be better.
It has the option "has more pages", a header and maybe footer (for receipts), with page numbers (1 of 2 or 1/2).

Comment: The fact that the tutorials you've found don't satisfy ALL your needs is no treason to throw out everything they provide. You just bed to adjust the code so that it DOES meet all your needs. We're not here to write your code from scratch or even to modify the code you have for you. We're here to help you fix specific issues you have with your code in trying to implement specific functionality.  If you haven't tried to implement that functionality yet, you haven't encountered a specific issue, so it's too early for a question here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, That's why I asked dude. Even if I post a code here it would just be re-written.
I'm not asking for someone to write from scratch, some users here post a link as guide.
And I already stated what I need, you are just being an ass here.
Looks like you just read the first sentence and made all of your comment to be a reply on just one sentence.

Comment: No, I'm not just being an ass. I'm asking you to use this site the way it is intended to be used. One of the specific reasons that a question should be closed here is that it is asking for an tutorial or other off-site resource to be recommended. It's a legitimate question some places but not here. Perhaps read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before claiming how mean people are being to you.